# Angular-material: input-group and md-buttons on same line

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm having some trouble trying to include an input-group and a couple of buttons on the same line using `angular-material`.

The following `HTML` structure produces the result you can see on the image below it, which is not what I want:

```
<section layout-align="end center" layout-padding flex>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" flex>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="monitor.query" placeholder="Search reports" aria-describedby="addon">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section layout-padding>
        <md-button class="md-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="monitor.newReport();">New Report</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-hollow disabled" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Export</md-button>
    </section>
</section>
```

[image]

However, if I try to include all elements within the same `layout="row"`, the `input-group` ends up taking all the space and pushing the buttons out of the parent div:

```
<section class="no-print" layout-align="end center" layout-padding flex>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" flex>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="monitor.query" placeholder="Search reports" aria-describedby="addon">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        </div>
        <md-button class="md-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="monitor.newReport();">New Report</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-hollow disabled" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Export</md-button>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Is there a right way of having an input group and a couple of buttons all on the same line using `angular-material` or do I have to create my own styles?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<form layout layout-align="center" layout-padding>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-input-container flex class="md-icon-float md-block md-title">
            <label>Your font number</label>
            <!-- below is the material icons -->
            <md-icon class="material-icons">phone</md-icon>
            <input type="text">
        </md-input-container>
        <div>
            <md-button class="md-raised">
            <!-- below is the material icons -->
                <md-icon class="material-icons">search</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

see a sample in the following link
http://codepen.io/cmwang-cottageclothing/pen/BjpdVQ?editors=1000

Comment: bootsrap is not used.

Comment: help needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494503/how-can-i-make-button-and-placeholder-in-same-line-using-material

Answer (score 44):

Would like to provide a contemporary answer to this popular question.

**1. Use [matSuffix] on the button**

Angular Material got you back on that one and provide [matSuffix](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatSuffix) directive to place an element at the end of the form field.

Hence, your solution would look like:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-placeholder>Search reports</mat-placeholder>
      <input matInput type="search">
      <button mat-button matSuffix mat-stroked-button aria-label="search">
        <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
```

See the full code of the example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvndsv.

**2. Make mat-form-field to fill the width**

To fulfil the width of the parent element, alter the style of `mat-form-field`:

```
mat-form-field.mat-form-field {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**3. Use CSS 'flex' properties, not `@angular/flex-layout` directives**

For big project, I'd recommend to use [flex CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and avoid using `flex` directives from [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) package.

While at the first glance, it may look handy to put a flex directive, rather than writing CSS styles, it will backfire on a bigger projects once the project start growing and you build your CSS classes 
and mixins and start extending them in the components:

1. 'flex' directives would bring ambiguity on where the style properties get applied from.
2. Debugging issues requires understanding the actual CSS flex properties, as you see/manipulate them in the browser's developer tools. So using the 'flex' directives:

   - would require devs to understand how the directive's properties get converted to the CSS;
   - and once they've got working CSS they have to manually convert it to directives, which introduces another point of failure.

Comment: @AnthonyWeston, I believe you're mistaken. All the tags of the post point to Angular and Angular Material (read descriptions on the tags, for example they say "_Do not use this tag for AngularJS Material_"). The problem description definitely can be applied to Angular Material. The only bit, which can be misleading is the HTML markup in the post referring to old prefixes used in Angular Material - they used to be `md-` and been changed to `mat-`.

Comment: best solution just replace `mat-stroked-button` with  `mat-icon-button`

Answer (score 4):

In the same material form field, use a button with matSuffix directive like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width w-full" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Request name</mat-label>
  <input type="tel" matInput>
  <button matSuffix>Create request</button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3):

In angular material you can do this by multiple way, one of the way by ::ng-deep  overriding style. For alignment of group input and button you can use flex boxes or table.

In component.html

```
<div fxFlex="40%">
    <mat-form-field floatLabel="auto" hideRequiredMarker appearance="outline">
         <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
         <input matInput type="text">                                                 
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div fxFlex="20%">
    <button mat-flat-button color="accent" type="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

In component.scss or css

```
mat-form-field {
    width: 100%;        
    input {
        width: 100%;
        caret-color: black; 
    }
}
button {
    margin-top: 4px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline {
    color: black !important;
    .mat-form-field-outline-end {
        border-radius: 0px !important;
    }
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: black !important;
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: black !important;
}
```