# How can i make icon and placeholder in same line using material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to make icon and search field should be in same line .

```
<div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

Above i added my html code ..

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jd2l6y-cpqk6n?file=app/table-filtering-example.html)

i wrote lot of css but i could't get this 
help me out to move forward..

Comment: added some CSS, you can check updated stackblitz now. the icon and text are on the same line. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jd2l6y-rmdqfx?file=styles.css

Comment: need one help .if user start typing i need to hide placeholder how can i do this ?

Answer (score 20):

Not sure why other answers are so complicated. Just use `matPrefix`  or `matSuffix` with `mat-button` (tested for Angular-material v7).

[Straight from docs:](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button mat-button matPrefix mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>


<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Clearable input">
  <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: It can also be used directly on the mat-icon

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
 <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>      
     <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" 
      placeholder="Filter">
    <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
 </div>
</div>
```

Just included matPrefix to mat-icon.

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: I will not include anything in the fiddle. Just included matPrefix.

Comment: i added this  matPrefix only but its not coming perfectly can you check that fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Apply this css it will align both in line

```
.mat-form-field-label {
    top: 12px;
}
.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label{
  top:18px;
}
```